# Swagger API documentation in an API gateway (spring-cloud-starter-gateway) does not work (Whitelabel Error Page)

Tags: java, spring-boot, swagger, spring-cloud

I am trying to add the Swagger API documentation in a Springboot application that uses the following dependency:

```
implementation 'org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-gateway'
```

I am using the following configuration:

```
@OpenAPIDefinition
@Configuration
public class SwaggerConfiguration {
    @Bean
    public OpenAPI baseOpenAPI(){
        return new OpenAPI().info(
                new Info()
                        .title("This is a test")
                        .version("0.1")
        );
    }
}
```

This is my controller:

```
@RestController
public class HelloWorldController {
    @GetMapping("/hello")
    public String hello() {
        return "Hello, World!";
    }
}
```

and my build.gradle:

```
plugins {
    id 'java'
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.7.11'
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.0.15.RELEASE'
}

group = 'com.noob234'
version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
sourceCompatibility = '1.8'

configurations {
    compileOnly {
        extendsFrom annotationProcessor
    }
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

ext {
    set('springCloudVersion', "2021.0.7")
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-webflux'
    implementation 'org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-gateway'
    implementation 'org.springdoc:springdoc-openapi-ui:1.6.15'
    compileOnly 'org.projectlombok:lombok'
    annotationProcessor 'org.projectlombok:lombok'
    testImplementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test'
    testImplementation 'io.projectreactor:reactor-test'
}

dependencyManagement {
    imports {
        mavenBom "org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-dependencies:${springCloudVersion}"
    }
}

tasks.named('test') {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}
```

I suspect that the issue is related to this dependency

```
implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-webflux'
```

because I tried the same steps without introducing the

```
implementation 'org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-gateway'
```

dependency and it works when I access this page http://localhost:8082/swagger-ui/index.html#/.
I don't get Whitelabel Error Page anymore.

**EDIT:**

I also tried to add these 2 dependencies:

```
implementation 'org.springdoc:springdoc-openapi-webflux-ui:1.6.15'
implementation 'org.springdoc:springdoc-openapi-webflux-core:1.6.15'
```

Instead of this one:

```
implementation 'org.springdoc:springdoc-openapi-ui:1.6.15'
```

And added these properties in my application.properties:

```
spring.application.name=gateway
server.port=8081
springdoc.swagger-ui.path=/swagger-ui.html
springdoc.api-docs.path=/v3/api-docs
springdoc.swagger-ui.enabled=true
spring.cloud.gateway.routes[0].id=swagger-ui
spring.cloud.gateway.routes[0].uri=http://localhost:8081
spring.cloud.gateway.routes[0].predicates[0]=Path=/swagger-ui.html

spring.cloud.gateway.routes[1].id=api-docs
spring.cloud.gateway.routes[1].uri=http://localhost:8081
spring.cloud.gateway.routes[1].predicates[0]=Path=/v3/api-docs
```

Please tell me if you can reproduce this issue if you follow the steps and what I should do to fix it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since api gateway uses webflux, instead of using swagger dependency

```
implementation 'org.springdoc:springdoc-openapi-ui:1.6.15'
```

use swagger webflux dependency

```
implementation 'org.springdoc:springdoc-openapi-webflux-ui:1.6.15'
```

Please find working repo [here](https://github.com/cricketbackground/docs) for reference

After updating this in build gradle swagger url works fine:

`http://localhost:8081/swagger-ui.html`

[image]

Comment: I know now what I did wrong! I was trying to acces this endpoint ```http://localhost:8081/swagger-ui/index.html#/``` instead of this one ```http://localhost:8081/swagger-ui.html```. Thank you!